# Getting the currently selected option as text/string for a drop down in Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a situation where I need to get the current selection from the drop down as a text or String and compare it for further assertion. But when I try the getText(), I get the complete list of items in the drop down. How can I get the currently selected item from drop down?

Hope my question makes sense, please let me know if anybody has done it before.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's your Selenium Java code you tried?

Answer (score 3):

This is the code which worked for me

```
Select comboBox = new Select(driver.findElement(locator);
String selectedComboValue = comboBox.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Hope it help others too!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
  //Assume driver initialized properly some where else
  Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Dropdown locator Id)));
  String strCurrentValue = sel.getFirstSelectedOption();
  //Print the Currently selected value
  System.out.println(strCurrentValue);
```

Use the above value for assertion purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know which text you're looking for....
This works for me

```
public String getValueFromDropDown(WebElement element, String compareText) {
        List<WebElement> options = new Select(element).getAllSelectedOptions(); 
    for (WebElement option : options){
        if (option.getText().equals(compareText)){
            return option.getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note: The other answers grab the first selected item. This checks all available options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below option in selenium to get the text value :

```
Driver.findElement(By.id("id value")).getVisibleText("enter value name");
```